# How would you translate "Log me out"?! (when asking someone to log yourself out of facebook account/ e-mail. etc)

Tags: перевод, информатика

I have difficulties to adequately translate this into Russian, so that translation is short and clear (not something clumsy like "Нажми на кнопку Выйти в моем профиле" or something unnatural like "Выйди меня (из почты/фейсбука)".

What would be a clear adequate and (preferably) short translation into Russian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what is meant is that you connected to something using your name and password and now someone else wants to use the computer but your session is still open. In this case, I usually say either "Выйди из моего эккаунта" or "Закрой мой эккаунт" ("account" is almost a Russian word nowadays), depending upon whether he is going to use the same/related application or an independent/different one.

Most of the computer terminology is russified English anyway, so no matter how hard you try,
you can choose only between the years the words became common and the degrees of their russification, not between a slavic root and a roman root.

Comment: Do you really insist on [that](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%FD%EA%EA%E0%F3%ED%F2&all=x) spelling?!

Comment: @peacefool Certainly not :-) As I said, it is an **almost** Russian word and it'll take some more time to transform into something like "сессия" or "профиль", so, no matter what various dictionaries are suggesting today, there is no really correct spelling of it yet. Note, by the way, that both the pronunciation and the spelling of "вылогинись, пожалуйста" and "логаутнись" strike my old-fashioned ears and eyes even more...

Comment: @peaceful Just to convince you that my spelling is no less recognized than the one you quoted: http://www.bank24.ru/info/glossary/?srch=%DD%CA%CA%C0%D3%CD%D2%C8%CD%C3

Comment: This is not an appropriate example for at least 2 reasons: 8)

ЭККАУНТИНГ is a business-related term only (not when speaking about some web-service profile like fb or e-mail) AND because it is another word) "ЭККАУНТИНГ" is just not "[э/а]ккаунт" 8)

But tx anyway, I believe the most appropriate phrase (at the moment) suggested is "Выйди из моего аккаунта"...

Comment: @peaceful I just meant that the spelling of the corresponding English sound is flexible and determined more by circumstances/precedents rather than by some ironclad logic/tradition, so, at the moment, it is how it is spoken and written by the majority of people that determines how it appears in the dictionaries, not vice versa, as it would be for words with longer history :-).

Answer (score 8):

I would prefer the following translation:

> Выйди из моего профиля в гуглоплюсе.

As for shorter translations - they will be more informal and/or slangish. Usually I hear something like:

> Выйди из-под меня в фейсбуке.

But the latter options sounds clumsy. The *account* has also many other more slangish translations: "учетка", "аккаунт" or even "акк".

---

@alex notes that there are two words for log in/log out: *залогиниться* and *разлогиниться*. There is also *перелогиниться* which means - log off and then log in again.

**Залогиниться** may be used by itself or with the name of login:

> Залогинься в фейсбук. Залогинься в программу как админ.

I have never heard **разлогиниться** to be used with the name of the account. It seems to be used only as "log off from current account":

> Разлогинься в фейсбуке на всякий случай.

**Перелогиниться** can also be used by itself or with name of account or user role:

> После изменения настроек перелогинься.
>   Перелогинься админом чтобы изменить настройки.

Another three options is using **зайди/выйди/перезайди**. All these options can be used with or without login or user role:

> Зайди админом. Выйди из-под админа. Перезайди админом.

If these words are used without login/user role it may be not clear that log in or log out is required when the software or the site does not require authentication. "Войди в Ворд" means just "open the Word application", while "Войди в 1С" implies "Open 1C accounting system and log in", because the latter application always requires authentication.

Looks like "Зайди подо мной. Выйди из-под меня. Перезайди подо мной." is derived from "админ" log in/log out expressions.

---

Here is Google search results. Estimated results (shown on the first page) are very different from ones shown on the last page. So, to obtain them I had to click on the last page of search results and sometimes click again on "show all results" if necessary to see skipped ones.

> 1. "выйди из моего профиля" - 72 results
> 2. "выйди из моего аккаунта" - 64 results
> 3. "выйди из моего акка" - 37 results
> 4. "разлогинь меня" - 31 results
> 5. "выйди из-под моего аккаунта" - 29 results
> 6. "выйди из-под меня" - 19 results
> 7. "выйди из моей учетки" - 9 results
> 8. "выйди из моего логина" - 6 results
> 9. "выйди из-под моего логина" - 3 results
> 10. "вылогинь меня" - 2 results
> 11. "перелогинься собой" - 2 results
> 12. "выйди из-под моего профиля" - 1 result

Many results seem to be requests to other users to stop using the account that does not belong to them. Also the word used for account (профиль, учетка, etc.) is dependent from the term that is used in site's user interface.

Also, the аккаунт seems more preferred - the sum of "выйди из моего аккаунта" and "выйди из-под моего аккаунта" gives 93 results.

Comment: "Выйди из-под меня"? Are you serious?

Comment: @Dima It is opposite for "Войди подо мной". I don't say it is preferred way to say it, but I hear this quite often.

Comment: @Artemix  Wow! o__O surprised and disappointed. Here in the Czech republic we have a slightly more polite computer-related slang.

Comment: @petajamaja Added Google statistics. And what do you use in Czech for these actions (login/logout/relogin)?

Comment: @Artemix, [odhlásit se](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/odhlásit) for logout, [přihlásit se](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/přihlásit) for login, and for relogin there is no word, they use "login again" (znovu se přihlásit). Basically, to make it an action done for someone, they just drop the reflexive particle **se**.

Comment: @petajamaja Do you consider "log **out of my** account" even more rude? In English people say "login **under** someone's accout" which is sometimes used as "login under me" (search it). I also searched for "enter under me" and got a lot of results. The Russian variant is just a literal translation.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the `Выйди из-под меня в ...` there is a couple of the new loan words from English 'login' : `залогиниться/разлогиниться`

```
Разлогинь меня в Фейсбуке
```

Google "залогиниться" About 1,390,000 results

Answer (score 3):

I think you are describing not a situation where one person asks another to log them out (which is what everyone answers above), but simply a "Log (me) out" button on a generic web site.

In this case the most common usage is "Войти" for "Log (me) in" and "Выйти" for "Log (me) out".

Comment: re:"not a situation where one person asks another..."
Exactly THIS situation, actually!

Answer (score 1):

As programmer, I think, in order to comply with your initial sentence `Log Me Out`, the best thing to say in Russian would be:

```
Завершить сессию
```

However, simply using `Выход` или `Выйти` also would work fine, and be the shortest but less exact (may be not always).

Saying `разлогиниться`, personally for me sounds nasty and I would never use it in my app.

Comment: "Завершить сессию" is grammatically ok, but I can hardly imagine using it when talking to a friend)
(so it's not quite appropriate).

And these "разлогинить", "разлогиниться" (e.g., "Разлогинь меня") and even "Выйди из-под меня"... Some of them are just bad, some should not even exist (but they do) in the 1st place...

Seems like the language does not yet have a no-nonsense word/phrase...

Comment: Just use `Выйти`, that's all you need and it will be understood correctly by everybody.